# How to add a colspan 4 within a datatable into a subtable in Primefaces 5.1?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Hello to Comunida have a question, I happen to have a value I want is displayed at the four cells when a condition is met if a variable is null.

[image]

As noticed is a main grid, has a rowExpansion within another datatable place where they see the value "SUPERVISION" only takes a field I want is displayed at the four cells left over.

**This is the original code of the previous screen:**

```
<p:panelGrid id="panelAdicionalMantenimiento" columns="1">

            <p:dataTable id="tblPresupuestoCosto" var="presupuestoCosto"
                         value="#{mAlias.listaCuadroCosto}"
                         emptyMessage="#{rsc['tabla.noExistenRegistros']}">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['cotizacion.form.cuadro.costos']}" />
                </f:facet>

                <p:column style="width:16px">
                    <p:rowToggler rendered="#{not empty presupuestoCosto.listaPreDetCosto}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="#{msg['form.item']}" width="20" style="text-align: center;">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{presupuestoCosto.iNumRegistro}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="#{msg['form.descripcion']}" style="text-align: center;">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{presupuestoCosto.vdesPreCosto}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="#{msg['cotizacion.form.subtotal']}">
                    <div style="text-align: right;">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{presupuestoCosto.nsubTotal}">
                            <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                        </p:outputLabel>
                    </div>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="#{msg['cotizacion.form.igv']}">
                    <div style="text-align: right;">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{presupuestoCosto.nigv}">
                            <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                        </p:outputLabel>
                    </div>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="#{msg['cotizacion.form.total']}">
                    <div style="text-align: right;">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{presupuestoCosto.ntotal}">
                            <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                        </p:outputLabel>
                    </div>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="" style="text-align: center;" width="40">
                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{mAlias.verDetallePreDetCosto}"
                        oncomplete="PF('dlgVarPreDetCosto').show()"
                        update=":mantenimientoAdicionalForm"
                        title="#{msg['cotizacion.form.anadir.cotizacion.costo']}"
                        icon="ui-icon-plusthick">
                        <f:param name="paramNumReg" value="#{presupuestoCosto.iNumRegistro}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="" style="text-align: center;" width="40">
                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{mAlias.editarDesPresupuestoCosto}"
                        oncomplete="PF('dlgVarNuevaUnidadCosto').show()"
                        update=":mantenimientoAdicionalForm"
                        title="#{msg['cotizacion.form.editar.cotizacion.costo']}"
                        icon="ui-icon-pencil">
                        <f:param name="paramNumReg" value="#{presupuestoCosto.iNumRegistro}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="" style="text-align: center;" width="40">
                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{mAlias.removerPresupuestoCosto}"
                        title="#{msg['cotizacion.form.remover.cotizacion.costo']}"
                        update=":mantenimientoAdicionalForm" icon="ui-icon-trash">
                        <f:param name="paramNumReg" value="#{presupuestoCosto.iNumRegistro}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>

                <p:rowExpansion rendered="#{not empty presupuestoCosto.listaPreDetCosto}"
                                styleClass="expand-table">
                    <br />
                    <div class="div-datatable">
                        <p:dataTable value="#{presupuestoCosto.listaPreDetCosto}"
                            var="preDetCosto" emptyMessage=""
                            rowKey="#{preDetCosto.iNumRegistro}">

                            <p:columnGroup type="header">
                                <p:row>
                                    <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="#{msg['form.item']}" />
                                    <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="#{msg['form.cantidad']}" />
                                    <p:column colspan="4" headerText="#{msg['form.descripcion']}" />
                                    <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="#{mAlias.formMantenimiento.vdesTipMoneda} #{msg['cotizacion.form.precio.unitario']}" />
                                    <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="#{mAlias.formMantenimiento.vdesTipMoneda} #{msg['cotizacion.form.precio.total']}" />
                                </p:row>
                                <p:row>
                                    <p:column colspan="1" headerText="#{msg['producto.form.producto']}" />
                                    <p:column colspan="1" headerText="#{msg['form.capacidad']}" />
                                    <p:column colspan="1" headerText="#{msg['form.marca']}" />
                                    <p:column colspan="1" headerText="#{msg['producto.form.electricidad']}" />
                                </p:row>
                            </p:columnGroup>

                            <p:subTable var="detalleCosto" value="#{preDetCosto.listaPreDetCosto}">
                                <p:columnGroup type="header">
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column style="text-align: center;">
                                            <f:facet name="header">
                                                <p:outputLabel value="#{preDetCosto.iNumRegistro}" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column />
                                        <p:column colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">
                                            <f:facet name="header">
                                                <p:outputLabel value="#{preDetCosto.vdesPreDetCosto}" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column />
                                        <p:column />
                                    </p:row>
                                </p:columnGroup>

                                <p:column />
                                <p:column style="text-align: right;">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.ncantidad} #{detalleCosto.vdesCorUniMedida}" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.vdesPreDetCosto}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.vcapacidad}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.vdesMarca}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.velectricidad}" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column style="text-align: right;">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.npreUnitario}">
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                                    </p:outputLabel>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column style="text-align: right;">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.npreTotal}">
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                                    </p:outputLabel>
                                </p:column>

                            </p:subTable>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </p:rowExpansion>

                <p:columnGroup type="footer">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align: right;"
                                  footerText="#{msg['cotizacion.form.subtotal']} #{mAlias.formMantenimiento.vdesTipMoneda}: " />
                        <p:column style="text-align:right">
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <h:outputText value="#{mAlias.formMantenimiento.npreSubTotal}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="text-align:right">
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <h:outputText value="#{mAlias.formMantenimiento.npreIgv}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="text-align:right">
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <h:outputText value="#{mAlias.formMantenimiento.npreTotal}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row rendered="#{mAlias.bestadoDescuento}">
                        <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right"
                            footerText="#{msg['cotizacion.form.descuento.especial']}: " />
                        <p:column style="text-align:right">
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <h:outputText value="#{mAlias.formMantenimiento.ndesSubTotal}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="text-align:right">
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <h:outputText value="#{mAlias.formMantenimiento.ndesIgv}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="text-align:right">
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <h:outputText value="#{mAlias.formMantenimiento.ndesTotal}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right"
                                  footerText="#{msg['cotizacion.form.total']}: " />
                        <p:column style="text-align:right">
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <h:outputText
                                    value="#{mAlias.formMantenimiento.ntotSubTotal}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="text-align:right">
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <h:outputText value="#{mAlias.formMantenimiento.ntotIgv}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="text-align:right">
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <h:outputText value="#{mAlias.formMantenimiento.ntotTotal}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" locale="en" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:columnGroup>

            </p:dataTable>
```

**And this would be with the modified code, all you did was add a conditional:**

```
<c:if test="${empty detalleCosto.icodProducto}">
    <p:column colspan="4">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.vdesPreDetCosto}" />
    </p:column>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty detalleCosto.icodProducto}">
    <p:column>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.vdesPreDetCosto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.vcapacidad}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.vdesMarca}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.velectricidad}" />
    </p:column>
</c:if>
```

[image]

But I notice that the colspan = "4" has no effect and alter the outcome, I hope you can give me a hint on how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jsf, you can use jsf notations. Avoid jstl (jsf and jstl are executed in different steps and can cause problems if you don't take it into account).
Instead of c:if you can use the rendered condition.

Try with this:

```
  <p:column colspan="4" rendered="${empty detalleCosto.icodProducto}">
      <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.vdesPreDetCosto}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column rendered="${not empty detalleCosto.icodProducto}">
      <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.vdesPreDetCosto}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column rendered="${not empty detalleCosto.icodProducto}">
      <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.vcapacidad}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column rendered="${not empty detalleCosto.icodProducto}">
      <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.vdesMarca}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column rendered="${not empty detalleCosto.icodProducto}">
      <p:outputLabel value="#{detalleCosto.velectricidad}" />
  </p:column>
```

Comment: Friend implement the change but the colspan not occupy the four cells, continues to occupy only one cell...